# make recompiles everything every time, why?

Tags: makefile

Here's my makefile:

```
all: lex yacc compile

lex: sql.l
    lex -i sql.l

yacc: sql.y
    yacc -d -v sql.y

compile: y.tab.c lex.yy.c
    $(CC) -o sql_parser y.tab.c lex.yy.c -ly -ll

test: all
    @./parsesql.sh selecttest.sql
    @./parsesql.sh insertintotest.sql
    @./parsesql.sh deletefromtest.sql
    @./parsesql.sh createtest.sql

cleanup:
    rm test.tab.cacc
    rm y.output
```

Running `make` will always trigger a full recompile, even if nothing has changed:

```
parsesql>  make
lex -i sql.l
yacc -d -v sql.y
cc -o sql_parser y.tab.c lex.yy.c -ly -ll
parsesql>  make
lex -i sql.l
yacc -d -v sql.y
cc -o sql_parser y.tab.c lex.yy.c -ly -ll
parsesql>  make
lex -i sql.l
yacc -d -v sql.y
cc -o sql_parser y.tab.c lex.yy.c -ly -ll
```

None of the files have changed, so why is it doing this? The `lex` and `yacc` commands should only trigger if `sql.l` or `sql.y` respectively have changed, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your targets are all not real files.  Make them the names of the actual files you're generating so that `make` can find them and check timestamps.

Example:

```
all: sql_parser

lex.yy.c: sql.l
    lex -i sql.l

y.tab.c: sql.y
    yacc -d -v sql.y

sql_parser: y.tab.c lex.yy.c
    $(CC) -o sql_parser y.tab.c lex.yy.c -ly -ll

test: all
    @./parsesql.sh selecttest.sql
    @./parsesql.sh insertintotest.sql
    @./parsesql.sh deletefromtest.sql
    @./parsesql.sh createtest.sql

cleanup:
    rm test.tab.cacc
    rm y.output
```

You can add `.PHONY: all test cleanup` to indicate to `make` that those targets are not intended to be real files.